# Rearranging data in a CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

I'm trying to rearrange a csv file. The file is set up something like this. I'm using Python 3 with the numpy and pandas libraries.

| Element | Temperature | Fy |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Element A | 27 | 320 |
| Element A | 100 | 310 |
| Element A | 200 | 300 |
| Element A | 300 | 290 |
| Element A | 400 | 280 |
| Element B | 27 | 320 |
| Element B | 100 | 310 |
| Element B | 200 | 300 |
| Element B | **350** | 290 |
| Element B | 400 | 280 |

The 1st column has the name of element, 2nd column has a temperature, 3rd column has a corresponding yield stress. Important to note that some elements may contain different temperature values. I need to reorganize the column to run horizontally.

| Element | 27 | 100 | 200 | 300 | 350 | 400 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Element A | 320 | 310 | 300 | 290 | 0 | 280 |
| Element B | 320 | 310 | 300 | 0 | 290 | 280 |

So far the code I have is this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('MatNavi.csv', header=0)
Elements = df['Element'].unique()                                      # Creates a numpy array of all elements, no duplicates, This will become my first column in the final csv file
X = df['Temperature'].drop(Mn[Mn['Element'] != 'Element A'].index)     #creates a numpy array with the temperature values then drops all temperature values that are not for Element A
Y = df['Fy'].drop(Mn[Mn['Element'] != 'Element A'].index)              #same thing but for Fy
```

This is where I am stuck. I need to make a list, array, or dataframe that has the X values (temperature) as my column headers and then the Fy values horizontally below that and have it correspond to the Element A row header. I'm assuming the temperature value should be the index (not sure if this is the correct term) that then pandas or numpy can use to categorize the Fy values in order. I just don't know how to start.

Answer (score 3):

Use Pivot:

```
df = df.pivot(values = 'Fy', index = 'Element', columns = 'Temperature').fillna(0, downcast='infer')
print(df)
```

output:

```
Temperature  27   100  200  300  350  400
Element
Element A    320  310  300  290    0  280
Element B    320  310  300    0  290  280
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks